# Bayesian monophyly testing from MrBayes and BEAST posterior tree samples

Tags: python

I wrote a script that tests monophyly by computing Bayes Factor on a sample of trees from Bayesian MCMC analysis from MrBayes and BEAST posterior tree sample files. This is the natural way I write code and am looking for improvement. I am trying to read some theoretical articles and other code, but that doesn't bring required results of changing my patterns as much as I would like to, so please be harsh.

The things I would like to know specifically:

- Iterators: are they worth it? Would I get better code/performance by having iterators instead of lists?
- Naming functions: I am quite confused with it. I like how bash use upper case for variables. I write functions often with camel case. But then, in lot of *good code practice* they say that I should use camel case for classes, which I don't really use, but then functions and variables have the same cases and aren't distinguishable.
- Classes: should I use them? I feel that most of the time, OOP is rather cumbersome and my style is closer to functional (is it thou?).
- Error handling: Am I doing it right? Is `sys.exit()` good use? It works when using it from console (`python BayesMonophyly.py [arguments]`), but when I want to test it in python shell, it exits the python shell.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys, re
import argparse as arg

"""This script will perform bayesian monophyly test on output from MrBayes or BEAST."""

def ParseArgs():
 parser = arg.ArgumentParser(prog="BayesMonophyly",description="Perform bayesian monophyly test on output from MrBayes or BEAST. " + \
                                                               "Test is simple comparison of number of trees that have monophyly " + \
                                                               "versus number of trees without monophyly, corrected by prior chance " + \
                                                               "of obtaining ratio of monophyletic/nonmonophyletic trees at random " + \
                                                               "(i.e., from data that contain no information regarding monophyly).")
 parser.add_argument("-s","--species",required=True, nargs="*", help="Species that should be monophyletic")
 parser.add_argument("-i","--input",required=True,nargs="+", help="One or more MrBayes or BEAST input files." + \
                                                                  "More files should be used only from the same analysis" + \
                                                                  "(i.e., where it actually make sense, such as standard" + \
                                                                  " two runs from MrBayes analysis).")
 parser.add_argument("-b","--burnin",required=False, default=0.2,type=int)
 args=parser.parse_args()
 return(args)

def ParseTreeFile(treefile,species):
 TEXT=[]
 try:
  FILE=open(treefile,"r")

 except IOError:
  print "ERROR: Couldn't open file, does file exists?" 
  sys.exit()
 else:
  with FILE:
   TEXT=FILE.readlines()


 #Various checks:
 #first line must be #NEXUS
 if(TEXT[0].strip("\n\t ").lower()!="#nexus"):
  print "ERROR: is file NEXUS?"
  sys.exit()
 #find begin trees
 begin_block_start=0
 for num,line in enumerate(TEXT):
  if line.strip("\n\t ").lower()=="begin trees;":
   begin_block_start=num
   break
 if begin_block_start==0:
  print "ERROR: Begin trees block not found!"
  sys.exit()
 #check if following one is translate:
 if TEXT[begin_block_start+1].strip("\n\t ").lower()!="translate":
  print "ERROR: Misformed Begin trees block, \"translate\" not found."
  sys.exit()
 #translate block, numbers from 1 to ntaxa
 #but because taxa block is not required 
 #number of taxa is not known and must be estimated from translate
 translated_taxa=dict()
 begin_block_end=0
 for num,line in enumerate(TEXT[begin_block_start+2:]):
  pair=line.strip("\n\t, ").split()
  if len(pair)!=2:
   begin_block_end=num+begin_block_start+2
   break
  else:
   translated_taxa[int(pair[0])]=pair[1]
 #check if begin_block_end has changed:
 if begin_block_end==0:
  print "ERROR: end of translation block not found."
  sys.exit()

 #test if all species are in translated_taxa
 taxa_in_tree=translated_taxa.values()
 for specie in species:
  if not specie in taxa_in_tree:
   print "ERROR: Species \"{0}\" is not in tree taxa!".format(specie)
   sys.exit()

 #now, every tree should start with "tree", so find a first tree, if not next:
 trees_start=0
 for num,line in enumerate(TEXT[begin_block_end+1:]):
  if line.strip("\n\t ")[0:4].lower()=="tree":
   trees_start=num+begin_block_end+1
   break
 #test if trees_start changed:
 if trees_start==0:
  print "ERROR: no tree was found!"
  sys.exit()

 trees=[]
 #read all trees and put them into list
 for line in TEXT[trees_start:]:
  #get tree
  line=line.strip("\n\t ;")
  if line.lower()=="end":
   #end of tree block
   break
  tree=line.split(" = ")[1].strip()
  if(tree[0:5]=="[&U] "): #remove "[&U] ", if present
   tree=tree[5:]
  #delete [&something=number] tags from BEAST
  #TODO better matching is required
  #in my file, I am currently matching only [&rate=number]
  if "[" in tree:
   tree=re.sub("\[&rate=[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*([eE]-[0-9]+)?\]","",tree)
  #get cladogram
  tree=re.sub(":[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*([eE]-[0-9]+)?","",tree)
  trees.append(tree)
 return(translated_taxa,trees)

def CheckSpeciesEquivalency(list_of_dicts):
 if len(list_of_dicts)==0:
  print "INTERNAL ERROR: In CheckSpeciesEquivalency: For some reason, no dictionary of translated_taxa was passed."
  sys.exit()
 elif len(list_of_dicts)==1:
  #with only one dict, no checking for equivalence is necessary
  pass
 else:
  #test every other dict against first dict:
  template_dict=list_of_dicts[0]
  template_dict_items=list_of_dicts[0].items()
  template_dict_items.sort()
  for num,matched_dict in enumerate(list_of_dicts[1:]):
   if len(template_dict)!=len(matched_dict):
    print "ERROR: Number of taxa in file 1 and file {0} is different!".format(num+2)
    sys.exit()

   matched_dict_items=matched_dict.items()
   matched_dict_items.sort()
   for template,matched in zip(template_dict_items,matched_dict_items):
    if template!=matched:
     print "ERROR: Number or taxa name differs in file 1 {1} and file {0} {2}! They are probably not equivalent!".format(num+2,str(template),str(matched))
     sys.exit()

def ete2solution(trees,translated_species):
 monophyletic_counter=0
 total_trees=len(trees)
 import ete2
 for tree in trees:
  try:
   ete2_tree=ete2.Tree(tree+";")
  except ete2.parser.newick.NewickError:
   print "INTERNAL ERROR: Problem with turning text into tree with ete2!"
   print tree
   sys.exit()

  try:
   if ete2_tree.check_monophyly(values=translated_species,target_attr="name")[0]:
    monophyletic_counter+1
  except ValueError:
   print "INTERNAL ERROR: Species are not in tree. Error in translating?"
   print translated_species
   print tree
   sys.exit()
 return(monophyletic_counter,total_trees)

def TranslateSpecies(translate_dict,species):
 reversed_dict={value:key for key,value in translate_dict.iteritems()}
 translated_species=[str(reversed_dict[item]) for item in species]
 return(translated_species)

def non_ete2solution(tree,species):
 """ I think that solution would be with re.sub"""
 pass #TODO

def NumberOfUnrootedTrees(n):
 import math
 return math.factorial(2*n-5)/(2^(n-3)*math.factorial(n-3))

def BayesFactor(num_monophyletic,num_total,num_taxa,num_species):
 posterior=num_monophyletic/num_total
 prior=NumberOfUnrootedTrees(num_taxa-num_species+1)/NumberOfUnrootedTrees(num_taxa)
 bayes_factor=(posterior/(1-posterior))/(prior/(1-prior))
 return(prior, posterior, bayes_factor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 args=ParseArgs()
 #analysis makes sense only for 2 and more species:
 if len(args.species)<2:
  print "ERROR: Must specify at least 2 species."
  sys.exit()
 #also, the species must be different:
 if len(set(args.species))<len(args.species):
  print "ERROR: Please, make sure that species are unique."
  sys.exit()

 #read all input files
 all_translated_taxa=[]
 all_trees=[]
 for input_file in args.input:
  (translated_taxa,trees)=ParseTreeFile(input_file,args.species)
  all_translated_taxa.append(translated_taxa)
  all_trees.append(trees)

 CheckSpeciesEquivalency(all_translated_taxa)
 #if equivalent, every file has same species, can use the first one
 #apply burnin
 all_trees_burned=[trees[int(len(trees)*args.burnin):] for trees in all_trees]
 all_trees_burned=[inner for outer in all_trees_burned for inner in outer]
 translated_species=TranslateSpecies(all_translated_taxa[0],args.species)
 (num_monophyletic,num_total)=ete2solution(all_trees_burned,translated_species)
 #print num_monophyletic,num_total
 (prior,posterior,bayes_factor)=BayesFactor(num_monophyletic,num_total,len(all_translated_taxa[0]),len(translated_species))
 #output:
 all_trees_burned_num=len(all_trees_burned)
 all_trees_num=sum([len(item) for item in all_trees])
 expected_monophyletic=int(round(prior*all_trees_burned_num))
 output="""Total trees read: {0}
Trees after burnin: {1}
Monophyletic trees found: {5}
Monophyletic trees expected: {3}
(in the case of noninformative data)

Prior: {2:.4f}
Posterior: {4:.4f}
Bayes factor: {6:.4f}""".format(all_trees_num,all_trees_burned_num,float(prior),expected_monophyletic,float(posterior),num_monophyletic,bayes_factor)
 print output
 if bayes_factor==0:
  print """Probability of this by chance alone given prior: {0:.2e}""".format((1-prior)**all_trees_burned_num)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style guide. Since you have ***many*** style violations, here's a list of many of them.

1. You need whitespace between certain things. For example, the expression `len(pair)!=2` would become `len(pair) != 2`, or `trees_start=0` would become `trees_start = 0`. You need whitespace around any operators, comparison, mathematical, etc.
2. It is the Python standard to indent any blocks of code by four spaces, or one tab, not one space.
3. There should be two blank lines between functions, classes, and code blocks at the top level. Not one.
4. Functions names, and variable names should be in `snake_case`. Class names should be in `PascalCase`.
5. You shouldn't group imports together on multiple lines. For example, the line `import sys, re` would become `import sys` and `import re`, both of these being on separate lines.
6. The docstring below your imports/includes should be at the very top of your file.
7. Finally, you should add some docstrings to your functions describing what they do.

---

Rather than printing a message and calling `sys.exit( ... )`, you could define a custom error and raise it. For example:

```
class MyCustomError(Exception): pass
raise MyCustomError("message here")
```

---

Finally, you're doing `len( ... )` a lot in your code. Are you sure that you shouldn't be using `len ( ... ) - 1`?

Comment: Thank you,
1. But does it really helps readability? (simple yes is sufficient)

2. four spaces is a lot, I understand that one space might not be enough, but... 4 spaces takes quite a lot of space. I understand that this is python style, but in other programming languages and in "own" style?

4. But again, what is the difference between function and variable?

7. But this would mean generating large number of custom errors, so the message would still remain informative, wouldn't it?

I don't think so. I am trying to get number of actual items in list, not just last index.

Comment: @Colombo You can also use a tab instead of four spaces, and the difference between a function and a variable is that the variable stores a value, and a function executes code, and *can* return a value.

Comment: @ethan--bierlein I know what is actual difference between function and variable. I meant how to distinguish the names, or it doesn't really matter and this is done through proper naming and the calling differences?

Comment: @Colombo If your functions have proper names, you should be able to distinguish between a function call or a variable being used in an expression.

Comment: Can I post it again after correction?

Comment: @Colombo Once you refactored your code accordingly, you can post a new question asking for review on the refactored code. Do not put your refactored code in this post though, as it is against site rules.